# Errors when creating a cumulative return column using for loop for each stock dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I get five stocks history price and want to create a column of cumulative return for each of them and i tried to use the for loop. But it returned the errors of "TypeError: 'Ticker' object is not subscriptable"

```
msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
apple=yf.Ticker("AAPL")
amzn=yf.Ticker("AMZN")
alibaba=yf.Ticker("BABA")
Tencents=yf.Ticker("TCEHY")

baba=alibaba.history(period="ytd")
msft=msft.history(period="ytd")
apple=apple.history(period="ytd")
Tencents=Tencents.history(period="ytd")
amzn=amzn.history(period="ytd")

for stock_df in (msft,apple,amzn,alibaba,Tencents):
    stock_df["cum-return"]=stock_df["Close"]/stock_df["Close"].iloc[0]
```

Can anyone help me with this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the array, you are iterating over `alibaba`, its type is `yf.Ticker`, you should replace that with `baba`instead, since `baba` is the `DataFrame`.

`Not subscriptable` means you are trying to slice an element which can't be sliced, for example `stock_df['cum-return]`, `yf.Ticker` don't support slicing.